# How to run a specific block of code automatically based on date and time?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am wondering how to make the application execute a specific part of code, for example a part of code to send an email on a specific time and date?

I have read the following questions but **none of the answers are correct** so I have decided to ask again as they are vary old and not easily visible. In addition my question is about executing a part of code not just sending email.

[send-automatic-mail-on-specific-date-through-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814590/send-automatic-mail-on-specific-date-through-java)
 [java-sending-mail-automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702917/java-sending-mail-automatically)

I do not care which framework I should use to solve it so two frameworks are chosen.

Please note, user should be able to do it manually, imagine user define a time to send a number of emails or set a timer for reminder alarm on the application.

Comment: @J888 you should probably accept answer from one of below :)

Answer (score 4):

I think using cron job for executing block of code on particular time interval would be a better option.
meanwhile you can go through [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) and [Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), who have done a better for my case.

Comment: even i have came across same situation. after little hickups, its working nicely now. I am using cron job for scheduling push notification to iOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using any library that hooks into cron. Cron is extremely flexible and can schedule things at any particular date, intervals, or any combination. So any library that hooks into it is probably what you want.

There are probably several libraries that can hook into cron, but I've had experience with a library called [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) and found it to work well, and was easy to start using quickly.

Answer (score 2):

you should use  [Quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/),

for that entries in pom.xml for dependency

step 2 : now create quartz.xml and entry like

```
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.test.schedule.RunScheduleJob" />

        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="runScheduleTask" value-ref="runScheduleTask" />
            </map>
        </property>

    </bean>         

    <!-- Cron Trigger -->
    <bean id="mailTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runScheduleJob" />
        <!-- <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/2 * * * ?" /> -->       
        <property name="cronExpression" value="1 0 00 * * ?" />
        <!-- <property name="cronExpression" value="0 10 16 L * ?" /> -->

    </bean>
```

step 3 : you will create a class where you extend QuartzJobBean

```
public class RunScheduleJob extends QuartzJobBean
{   

    private RunScheduleTask runScheduleTask;


    public RunScheduleJob() {
        runScheduleTask=new RunScheduleTask();
    }

    public RunScheduleTask getRunScheduleTask() {
        return runScheduleTask;
    }
    public void setRunScheduleTask(RunScheduleTask runScheduleTask) {
        this.runScheduleTask = runScheduleTask;
    } 
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)throws JobExecutionException   
{ 
         Trigger tri =  context.getTrigger();
         if(tri.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mailTrigger")){
             runScheduleTask.sendMailSmsOn();
         }
    }
}
```

step 4 : from that class you will call all method from class RunScheduleTask
    public class RunScheduleTask {

```
    private IAdminService adminService;



    public IAdminService getAdminService() {
        return adminService;
    }
    public void setAdminService(IAdminService adminService) {
        this.adminService = adminService;
    }   

    public void sendMailSms{
        try{

            adminService.sendMailSmsOnBeforeExpirationDate();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occured in sendMailSmsOnBeforeExpirationDate ", e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said if this is server or client - but if you just want a client side application to check the time and then take some action, you could define the action as a function, get the time, check if the time fits within a particular time period and run the function if it does. Something like this:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()    {
  var time=new Date().getHours();
    if (8 <= time && time <= 14)
           {
        yourFunction();
           }
    else 
           {
        anotherfunction();
           }
     });
```

If you need date and time it's easy enough to refine the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Framework (according to the tags), I think using [@Scheduled](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation will be the simplest way to accomplish your target.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz have a limited datasource support, Jobrunr is better suited where you have multiple datasource options. https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr